# How can I get floating left divs to expand if there isn't a div floating right

Tags: css, html

I have a div that contains three child divs of equal lengths with an image div(it can be a child but it doesn't have to be) to the right. The way my CMS works I can use the statement [if image] to make the image div show up if there's an image loaded. But I can't tell the first three child divs to behave differently if there isn't an image. I want them to be 800px like the parent if there isn't an image but be 490px if there is an image to make room for the image to float right. Unfortunately there isn't an "else" function to my CMS' "if" function.

The parent divs are stories so there are multiple parent divs on a page that the CMS loads. If there's an image I want to the CMS [if image] to display as the dog does below.
http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y44/elfshadowreaper/example1.jpg

But for stories without an image I want the width of the child divs to increase to 800px like this.
http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y44/elfshadowreaper/example2.jpg

Here's the basic code I have:
HTML

```
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="child_div_a">
    </div>
    <div class="child_div_b">
    </div>
    <div class="child_div_c">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="image_div"> <!-- this doesn't have to be outside the parent div if it'll work that way-->
    <img src="www">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent_div {
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
}
.child_div_a {
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
}
.child_div_b {
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
}
.child_div_c {
    width: 490px;
    float: left;
}
.image_div {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over complicating the situation.  Only the image needs to float right.  The other div don't need any float applied to them.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about.  Put the image div before the other divs inside of the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/NY2G3/1/

```
<div>
    <div  style='float:right; display: block; width: 300px;'><img style='width: 300px;' src='http://image.motortrend.com/f/oftheyear/car/1301_2013_motor_trend_car_of_the_year_tesla_model_s/41007848+w623+h388+cr1+ar0/2013-Tesla-Model-S-front-three-quarter-2.jpg' /></div>
    <div>span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1span 1</div>
 <div>span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2span 2</div>
 <div>span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3span 3</div>

</div>
```

The divs will make room for the floating element.
And if the image div isn't there, the divs take the full width of the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/NY2G3/2/

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be something I was overlooking. I'm only a few months into coding so I'm proud of myself that I was able to get this far without asking a question on stackoverflow. This site has been an invaluable source of help for me. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help. This site is so great for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Move the image_div first in the mark up and float only it in the right.

```
.image_div { float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red; }
.parent_div { background-color: blue; }
.parent_div div { height: 50px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XkLSM/)